# Com InvokeHelper Problem

Tags: com

I have found the following snippet of code on the internet, which creates an email from a template:

```
LPDISPATCH _Application::CreateItemFromTemplate(LPCTSTR TemplatePath, const VARIANT& InFolder)
{
    LPDISPATCH result;
    static BYTE parms[] =
        VTS_BSTR VTS_VARIANT;
    InvokeHelper(0x10b, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_DISPATCH, (void*)&result, parms,
        TemplatePath, &InFolder);
    return result;
}
```

The problem that I have with this code is that it requires the last parameter to have a folder. With my code there is no folder, the email after it sent will be uploaded into another application. I have tried passing `NULL` as the last parameter, but this just throws an exception.

All I am trying to achieve is to open an email using a template with it visible on the user's Outlook Desktop. Therefore, my question is what should I pass as the parameters to this `InvokeHelper` method? Is it just the last parameter, or the last parameter be `NULL`, but the others changed, if so to what?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [DISPID and Opening Emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923871/dispid-and-opening-emails)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
try 
{
    long rc = -1;
    static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BSTR VTS_BSTR VTS_BSTR VTS_BSTR VTS_BSTR VTS_I2;

    m_eventDispatchDriver.InvokeHelper(0x6003000c, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&rc, parms,
                                       _UDATA(strSubject), 
                                       _UDATA(strBody), 
                                       _UDATA(strBody),
                                       _UDATA(strRecipients), 
                                       _UDATA(strAttachments),
                                       0 /*SendWithMailToIfOLDown*/);

    if (rc == 0)
        return RESULT_OK;
    else
        return RESULT_E_FAIL;
}
catch(COleDispatchException *pExeption)
{
    _UCHAR szError[256];
    pExeption->GetErrorMessage(szError, 256);
    LOG(failure: %s", _UADATA(strCommand), szError);
    return RESULT_E_FAIL;
}
```

where:

strSubject = ""

strAttachments = ""

strRecipients = "name@addr.com"

strBody = ""

after you get this to work, you can play with the parameters...

Comment: BTW- all of the strings are of type UString